# Парсер на питоне медленно работает

Tags: python, парсер

Написал парсер для озона, обходящий их блок. Паршу данные из апи, но слегка замудрёным способом, потому что другого решения придумать не смог. Целиком программа выполняется достаточно долго, хотя данные со страницы забираются быстро, все остальные действия тоже выполняются быстро, но при отладке я заметил, что в этом участке кода:

```
        for item in dictionary2.items():
            if item[0] in tmparr:
                dictionary2[f'{item[0]}'] = json.loads(item[1])
```

программа залагивает на несколько секунд(именно перед первой итерацией), после чего снова работает исправно. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

```
class ucDriver:
    def __init__(self, url: str):
        self.exceptions = None
        try:
            if url == '' or url == None:
                raise ValueError
            else:
                self.url = url
        except ValueError:
            self.exceptions = 'None URL'

    def savePage(self):
        try:
            options = undetected_chromedriver.ChromeOptions()
            options.headless = True
            driver = undetected_chromedriver.Chrome(options=options, driver_executable_path="C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\dev\\chromedriver\\chromedriver.exe")
            driver.get(self.url)
            self.cookies = driver.get_cookies()
            return driver.page_source
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        finally:
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()


    ucdr = ucDriver(url=url)
    if ucdr.exceptions is None:
        html = ucdr.savePage()
        html = html[131:]
        html = html[:-20]
        ucdr.url = url + '/?layout_container=pdpPage2column&layout_page_index=2'
        html2 = ucdr.savePage()
        html2 = html2[131:]
        html2 = html2[:-20]
        dictionary = json.loads(html)['widgetStates']
        dictionary2 = json.loads(html2)['widgetStates']
        tmparr = ['webGallery-393698-default-1', 'webCharacteristics-545710-default-1', 'webAddToFavorite-1255799-default-1', 'webSale-849839-default-1', 'webAspects-418255-default-1', 'webCharacteristics-939965-pdpPage2column-2']
        if html is not None:
            for item in dictionary2.items():
                if item[0] in tmparr:
                    dictionary2[f'{item[0]}'] = json.loads(item[1])
            for item in dictionary.items():
                if item[0] in tmparr:
                    dictionary[f'{item[0]}'] = json.loads(item[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем вы перебираете все `items()` словаря, если по факту вам нужны всего несколько элементов оттуда? Я подозреваю, что итерирование по всем `items()` словаря - это очень затратная операция. Я бы пошёл от обратного - перебирал только те **ключи** словаря (а не `items()`), которые вам нужны, и только для нужных элементов уже брал значения:

```py
            for key in tmparr:
                if key in dictionary2:
                    dictionary2[key] = json.loads(dictionary2[key])
                if key in dictionary:
                    dictionary[key] = json.loads(dictionary[key])
```

Comment: В целом, вы правы, но я узнал что у ключей словаря цифры после ключа у разных товаров могут быть разные(без понятия зачем бекендеры озона создали это чудище)

Comment: Я изменил код и теперь перебираю только ключи словаря, скрипт работает чуть быстрее, но все же медленно

Comment: Ключи вашего словаря `tmparr` как у меня в коде или ключи тех больших (подозреваю) словарей перебираете? Сделайте как у меня в коде - и тогда быстро должно быть. Хотя зависит от много чего. Сколько элементов в каждом из словарей хотя бы?

Comment: В каждом словаре по 91 ключу.

Comment: Да, вы правы, я перебираю ключи тех больших словарей.

Comment: Ну, 91 это немного так то вообще. Мне кажется `json.loads` скорее должен тормозить.

Comment: Я сначала подумал точно также, но залаг происходит до 1 итерации цикла, после чего все 91 итерация выполняется быстро, поэтому я даже представить не могу из-за чего именно код тормозит